# Stop jQuery toggle from sliding content in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a simple jQuery .toggle hoping it would show/hide my content on click. It does that but my content always slides in from left to right until it's where it should be. I don't want it to slide in. Is there a better jQuery method for this or a property I need to specify?

Thanks! This is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(
            function(){
                $('.img-lg').click(function () {
                    $('.content').toggle("slow");
                });
            }
        );
```

Comment: Try with fadeIn and fadeOut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$('.content').toggle("slow")` to `$('.content').toggle()`. This will remove the transition